# ImageMagick only tiles firs row

Tags: imagemagick, crop, tiles

I am executing this command:

`convert -monitor -crop 20x20@ +repage +adjoin testImage.jpg image_%03d.jpg`

With some JPGs it only tiles the first row and stops without any error message. However in some cases it does work properly and generates al the tiles.

This is the [image](https://fossil.swau.edu/tail-test/testImage.jpg) to tile.

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine on v6.9.5 - are you using an old version?

Comment: I am using v6.8.9 the default update for ubuntu. I may have to upgrade it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to manually upgrade the ImageMagick package.
In Ubuntu the apt-get command will only upgrade to v6.8.9 which still has the problem.

I had to download the latest version, compile and install it manually like the old days.

Now I am using v7.0.3 and it is cropping all the tiles. :-)

[This website shows hot to do compile the latest version.](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29006)

Thank you Mark Setchell for suggesting the upgrade.